# Calendar dates are not equal

Tags: java, date, calendar, compare

I am having problem with java Calendar dates.
Bassically I have a list of holidays and want to check if a date belong
to the list. Still confused about how the Calendar class
is creating and formating its dates.

Please see the folowing code sample:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class CompareCalendarDates {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Date date1 = null;
    try {
        date1=  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2019-12-25");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        date1 = null;
    }

    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.clear();
    calendar1.setTime(date1);

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.clear();
    calendar2.setLenient(false); // Don't automatically convert invalid date.
    calendar2.set(2019, 11, 25, 0, 0, 0);
    calendar2.getTimeInMillis();

    boolean isEqual = calendar1.equals(calendar2);
    System.out.println ("Are to dates equal: " + isEqual);
}
}
```

I'm creating in 2 dates using different methods from Calendar class.
In my opinion the dates should be equal but there are not.
What am I missing? What is the difference between the methods
setTime () and set ?

Comment: Don't use `Calendar`, instead use the `java.time` types introduced in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDate
.parse( "2019-12-25" ) 
.isEqual(
    LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.DECEMBER , 25 )
)
```

> true

## Details

Never use `Date`/`Calendar`. Use only *java.time* classes.

## `LocalDate::isEqual`

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-12-25" ) ;

LocalDate other = LocalDate.of( 2019, 11, 25 ) ;
```

Compare using `isEqual`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`.

```
boolean sameDates = ld.isEqual( other ) ;
```

This has been addressed many many times already on Stack Overflow. So I am keeping this Answer brief. Search to learn more.

## December versus November

Unlike those legacy classes, the *java.time* classes use sane numbering. Months are counted 1-12 for January-December.

So notice that your pair of inputs differ, one for December, and one for November.

For clarity, you can use `Month` enum rather than an integer. Another benefit of enums is to ensure valid values.

```
LocalDate other = LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.NOVEMBER , 25 ) ;
```

Comment: I have to use Calendar in my legacy code but I will keep your advise in mind for future code refactoring.

Comment: @MagdelenaFairfax You can easily convert back and forth by calling new `from…` & `to…` conversion methods added to the old classes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
boolean isEqual = calendar1.getTime().equals(calendar2.getTime());
```

Instead of

```
 boolean isEqual = calendar1.equals(calendar2);
```

because the equals() method in Calendar class looks like these:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
}
```

So it checks if the dates in these two calendars are the **same** objects, and in your case they are not the same objects, they jut have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

If you have got a `Calendar` object from a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time, the modern Java date and time API, just now, and you want to know whether it denotes the same date as some string, convert both to `LocalDate` and compare using the `isEqual` method:

```
    String date1Str = "2019-12-25";
    Calendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25);
    
    LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(date1Str);
    LocalDate date2 = ((GregorianCalendar) calendar2).toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate();
    
    boolean isEqual = date1.isEqual(date2);
    System.out.println ("Are to dates equal: " + isEqual);
```

Output:

> Are to dates equal: true

A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day, time zone, and all the other things that an old-fashioned `Calendar` object carries with it. So comparing two `LocalDate` will give you the result that you had expected.

### What went wrong in your code?

While your two `Calendar` objects do denote the same point in time and also the same calendar date (which is not the same thing to ask), there are some differences, for example:

1. `calendar1` has got all its fields set while `calendar2` has got some uncomputed fields including for example era, week of year, AM/PM, millisecond of second and zone offset.
2. `calendar1` is lenient, `calendar2` is not.

I believe that this is more than enough that the objects are not considered equal. I haven’t checked the documentation for the exact criteria. You may do that out of curiosity, but I suggest that you don’t need to because you are not going to need to compare two `Calendar` objects for equality.

To answer your question, it seems that `setTime()` sets all fields while `set` obviuosly only sets some. I was surprised to see that `getTimeInMillis()` didn’t calculate the rest, but it doesn’t.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.